Render Error al tratar de mostrar con un boton una lista desplegable
Estoy intentando aprender react-native y estoy practicando a poner botones y al presionarlos aparezcan distintos objetos en pantalla como varias listas desplegables o listas de items, en este caso al presionar el boton o TouchableOpacity 'Voladores' me salta el siguiente error (uso expo)
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:undefined.
Check the render method of 'AppContent'.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaProvider, useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { SelectList } from 'react-native-element-dropdown'; 

function AppContent() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const [showVoladores, setShowVoladores] = useState(false); // Estado para mostrar u ocultar los voladores
  
  const DesplegarVoladores = () => {
    setShowVoladores((prev) => !prev); // Cambiar el estado de mostrar u ocultar los voladores
  };
  
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(""); // Estado para manejar la selección en el Dropdown
  
  const ubicacionVoladores = [
    { label: 'Aire', value: 'aire' },
    { label: 'Tierra', value: 'tierra' },
    { label: 'Agua', value: 'agua' },
  ];

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={[styles.container, { paddingTop: insets.top }]}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchable} onPress={DesplegarVoladores}>
            <Text>Voladores</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchable}>
            <Text>Caminadores</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchable}>
            <Text>Roedores</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        {/* Mostrar u ocultar los voladores */}
        {showVoladores && (
          <View>
            <SelectList 
              setSelected={setSelected} // Método correcto para manejar la selección
              data={ubicacionVoladores}
              save="value" // Guarda el valor seleccionado
              placeholder="Selecciona una opción"
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <AppContent />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}


El problema ocurre al desplegar la lista? Verificaste que el SelectList este instalado ? npm install react-native-element-dropdown

Hola! gracias por comentar. Asi es, ocurre al desplegar la lista, tengo instalado el selectlist tambien

Bueno despues de una buena noche de investigación resulta que hay algun problema con el paquete de SelectList con expo al menos en la version 52.0.10 que es la que uso. Lo solucione cambiando a un Dropdown
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown/v/2.12.2?activeTab=readme
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaProvider, useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown'; // Usamos Dropdown directamente.

function AppContent() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const [showVoladores, setShowVoladores] = useState(false); // Estado para mostrar u ocultar los voladores
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(""); // Estado para manejar la selección en el Dropdown

  const ubicacionVoladores = [
    { label: 'Aire', value: 'aire' },
    { label: 'Tierra', value: 'tierra' },
    { label: 'Agua', value: 'agua' },
  ];

  const DesplegarVoladores = () => {
    setShowVoladores((prev) => !prev); // Cambiar el estado de mostrar u ocultar los voladores
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={[styles.container, { paddingTop: insets.top }]}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchable} onPress={DesplegarVoladores}>
            <Text>Voladores</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchable}>
            <Text>Caminadores</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchable}>
            <Text>Roedores</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        {/* Mostrar u ocultar los voladores */}
        {showVoladores && (
          <View>
            <Dropdown
              data={ubicacionVoladores}
              search
              maxHeight={200}
              labelField="label" // Define la clave que contiene el texto visible
              valueField="value" // Define la clave que contiene el valor interno
              value={selected} // Valor actualmente seleccionado
              placeholder="Selecciona una opción"
              onChange={(item) => {
                setSelected(item.value); // Cambiar el valor seleccionado
              }}
              style={styles.dropdown} // Estilo del componente Dropdown
              placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle} // Estilo del texto del placeholder
              selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle} // Estilo del texto seleccionado
              inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle} // Estilo del input de búsqueda
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <AppContent />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  touchable: {
    margin: 8,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  dropdown: {
    height: 50,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  placeholderStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'gray',
  },
  selectedTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'black',
  },
  inputSearchStyle: {
    height: 40,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

